# React HOC TypeScript get rid of any type with Redux connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

General idea is a wrapper component that provides translation ability.

Btw, full example is here https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hellman-v84ed or GitHub https://github.com/hitrov/translation-wrapper

Here's HOC signature

```
export const wrapper = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  (props: P & WithReplacementProps & IProps) => {...}
```

Argument component must provide content by

```
interface WithReplacementProps {
  translatableProps: {
    getHeader(): string;
    getContent(): string;
  }
}
```

Redux should inject

```
interface IProps {
  language: string;

  setLanguage(language: string): SetLanguage;
}
```

and that's how it's being done

```
type StateProps = Pick<IProps, | 'language'>;
type DispatchProps = Pick<IProps, | 'setLanguage'>;
type OwnProps = Omit<
  IProps,
  keyof StateProps | keyof DispatchProps
>;

const connector = connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps, RootState>((state: RootState) => ({
  language: state.language,
}), {
  setLanguage,
});
```

The problem is that I always getting TypeScript errors when I'm trying to replace `<any>` with something that would allow safely check types.

```
export function withReplacement<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  return connector(wrapper<any>(Component));
}
```

here's finally how I use wrapped component

```
const ContentWithReplacement = withReplacement(Content);
...
<ContentWithReplacement
          key={header}
          header={header}
          content={content}
          translatableProps={{
            getContent: () => content,
            getHeader: () => header,
          }}
        />
```

Content component is straighforward

```
export function Content(props: ContentProps) {
  const { translatedProps } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{translatedProps && translatedProps.header}</h1>
      <p>{translatedProps && translatedProps.content}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `import { ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'; type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;` this didn't help me also

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. This helped me a lot https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#--nested-hoc---wrapping-a-component-injecting-props-and-connecting-to-redux-

That's how my connected HOC looks like at the moment

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";
import { reducer } from "../reducers";
import { Select } from "../Select";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from "../reducers/redux";
import { setLanguage, SetLanguage, } from '../reducers/language';
import { Diff } from 'utility-types';

interface InjectedProps {
  language: string;

  setLanguage(language: string): SetLanguage;
}

interface WithReplacementProps {
  translatableProps: {
    getHeader(): string;
    getContent(): string;
  }
}

export const withReplacement = <BaseProps extends {}>
(Component: React.ComponentType<BaseProps>) => {

  const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    language: state.language,
  });

  const dispatchProps = {
    setLanguage: (language: string) => setLanguage(language),
  };

  type PropsFromRedux = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
    typeof dispatchProps & {
    // here you can extend ConnectedHoc with new props
    // overrideCount?: number;
  };

  const Hoc = (props: PropsFromRedux & WithReplacementProps) => {

    const { translatableProps, language, setLanguage, ...rest } = props;

    const [ showOriginal, setShowOriginal ] = useState(true);

    const { getHeader, getContent } = translatableProps;
    let header = getHeader();
    let content = getContent();

    const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, {...);

    return (
      <>
        <Component
          {...rest as BaseProps}
          translatedProps={{
            header,
            content,
          }}
        />
        <Select
          language={language}
          onChange={e => {
            setLanguage(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </>
    );
  };

  return connect<ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>,
    typeof dispatchProps, // use "undefined" if NOT using dispatchProps
    Diff<BaseProps, InjectedProps>,
    RootState>(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatchProps
  )(Hoc);
};
```